# Vaadin 24 - Variable Not Updating Value

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a GRID with filtering that is working great. I want to be able to show the number of rows that are showing in the filtered set so I created a `recordCountStr` variable, and when the grid data is fetched (either when loading or after filtering) - I set the `recordCountStr` to the number of records in the grid.

The issue is that it will only show the record count on the initial load, and not after the filter changes the number of rows.

I'm new to Vaadin - so sorry if this is a stupid question... but I assumed if I updated the variable value - it would just redraw itself - but I guess that's not the case?

Here's basically what I'm doing:

```
public class myGridSetup extends Composite<VerticalLayout>{

    private Grid<Person> grid;
    private final VerticalLayout gridBody = new VerticalLayout();
    private final HorizontalLayout filterRow = new HorizontalLayout();
    private final Button applyFilterBtn = new Button("Apply Filters");
    private String recordCountStr = "0 Records";

    pubic myGridSetup(){
        filterRow.setWidthFull();
        filterRow.add(recordCountStr);
        
        applyFilterBtn.addClickListener(e -> getData(grid));
        
        filterRow.add(applyFilterBtn); 
        filterRow.add(recordCountStr);
        
        createGrid();
        getData(grid);
        gridBody.add(grid);
            
        getContent().add(filterRow);
        getContent().add(gridBody);
    }
    
    private void getData(Grid grid) {
        ListDataView dataView = grid.setItems(dataService.findAll(activeFilterValue));
        recordCountStr = dataView.getItemCount() + " Records Found";
    }

    private Component createGrid(){
        grid = new Grid<>(People.class, false);
        ...
        Grid creation here
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`recordCountStr` is a plain String. When you add a String to a Layout, it actually invokes this overload of the method `add`:

```
    default void add(String text) {
        this.add(new Text(text));
    }
```

And after you override the variable `recordCountStr`, the variable `text` in the above method keeps pointing to the old String. You could call `add` again with the new value, but then you'll have the old `Text` there as well.

As a better solution, you could create a wrapper Component, such as a `Span`, and replace `recordCountStr` with it. Now your `getData` method can update the Span instead of replacing the String reference:

```
    private Span recordCountSpan = new Span("0 Records");
    ...
    pubic myGridSetup(){
       ...
       filterRow.add(recordCountSpan);
       ...
    }


    private void getData(Grid grid) {
        ListDataView dataView = grid.setItems(dataService.findAll(activeFilterValue));
        recordCountSpan.setText(dataView.getItemCount() + " Records Found");
    }
```

Comment: Ah! Wow - EXCELLENT suggestion - I VERY MUCH appreciate you pointing me in the right direction!